# why View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION was affected the statusBar

Tags: android

i use this code，but statusBar was affected，how can i only ，effect navigationBar。

`window.navigationBarColor=ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.blue_beautiful_color) val option = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =option`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLfrK.png)